# How can I return a dynamic data using methods in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am having a variable that needs to return data according to the array of objects.

There are 3 dummies which are dynamic in such a way -->

---

Example:

- dummy1_A, dummy1_B, dummy1_C, ...
- dummy2_A, dummy2_B, dummy2_C, ...
- dummy3_A, dummy3_B, dummy3_C, ...

I want to set 'fieldName' and 'text' while returning.
And this is my code. I have to use JSON.stringify to show the data I need

Also, I am using map method

```
let a1 = [
  {
    dummy1_A: 0.5526714707565221,
    dummy2_A: 0.5526714707565223,
    dummy3_A: 0.5526714707565224,
    dummy1_B: 0.5028423429150607,
    dummy2_B: 0.5028423429150605,
    dummy3_B: 0.5028423429150604,

  },
  {
    dummy1_A: 0.542947572819916,
    dummy2_A: 0.4965857885945633,
    dummy3_A: 0.4965857885945677,
    dummy1_B: 0.4470431086251489,
    dummy2_B: 0.3785646261205342,
    dummy3_B: 0.3785646261205345,
  },
];

let a2 = a1.map((x, i) => {
  let seqStr = String(a1.entries); // I need some help here
  return {
    text: seqStr,
    fieldName: seqStr,
  };
});

// output
[
  { text: 'dummy1_A', fieldName: 'A' },
  { text: 'dummy2_A', fieldName: 'A' },
  { text: 'dummy1_B', fieldName: 'B' },
  { text: 'dummy2_B', fieldName: 'B' },
];
```

We can also use forEach but this also need more logic

```
a1.forEach(obj => {
  const key = Object.keys(obj)[0];
  const newKey = key[key.length - 1];
  obj[newKey] = obj[key];
  delete obj[key];
});
```

I have used console.log(JSON.stringify(a2)); Though I was using map but not got such result

Comment: @SebastianSimon I was trying with this let a2 = a1.map((x, i) => {
  let seqStr = String(a1.length-1);
  return {
    text: seqStr,
    fieldName: seqStr,
  };
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let newHeaders1 = a1.map( i => {
  return {
    text: i,
    fieldName: 'dummy1_'+i,
    width: 110
  };
});
```

Use this and create 2 more arrays with 2 and 3 respectively.

Then consolidated all the variable in an array using concat or spread operator